# I can't access my account

Tags: google-plus

when recovery email address is not provided in g mail account then how can I answer to Google for my disabled account?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Google Account Recovery process? Please click [here](https://www.google.com/accounts/recovery/).

Comment: Yes click on Google Account Recovery process but they said that my account has been disabled. My email address is himalayafabrics@gmail.com. This account has been disabled. But when I use contact us option to enable my account.I have to put that Email address which is currently linked to my disabled account after contact us option page.. But problem is that I didn't add any alternate email address  while preparing account himalayafabrics@gmail.com. what can I do under this situation